# jquery code to change the parameters submitted by a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

In a web form in a PHP program, the form is a regular HTML form.

Now, the form has 3 separate text boxes. Let their IDs/names be box1, box2 and box3 respectively

What I want to happen is, when the form gets posted --

The following text gets posted--> box1 + box2+ box3 contents, separated by commas.

I wish to do this using JQuery- I looked up JQuery "submit" function but could not find any direct way to replace the parameters-- how can I implement the above?

Comment: you can do that using `jQuery.ajax`, example : `data:{'boxes':$('#box1').val()+","+$('#box2').val()+","+$('#box3').val()}`

Comment: @mgraph ok- once i get the combined data into the new variable, now how do I submit the form-- replacing the 3 boxes params with the new single param(having combined value)? If you could post a JS snippet showing this that would be very helpful. Also instead of a comment kindly post that as an answer? Thanks, Arvind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this :

```
$('#yourForm').submit(function(e){

    var form = $(this)

    //Do you validation

    if(isValid){
        var mergedInput = $('<input/>');
        var inputToMerge = ['#box1','#box2','#box3'];
        var valueToMerge = $.map(inputToMerge, function(selector){
            val = $(selector).val()
            $(selector).remove()
            return val;
        })
        mergedInput.val(valueToMerge.join(','));
        mergedInput.prop('name', 'mergedInput')


        mergedInput.appendTo(form);

    }else{
        return false;
    }
})
```

Basicly, it is merging your input into one accessible via php with `['mergedInput']`.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can do this easily using ajax .. Kindly check [Change contents of submitted form on submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511316/change-contents-of-submitted-form-on-submit)

if you want to do this without ajax, you may have to use hidden fields .. Kindly check [jquery-add-additional-parameters-on-submit-not-ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530635/jquery-add-additional-parameters-on-submit-not-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX to solve your problem

Your HTML

```
<form onsubmit="return sendBoxes()">
  <input type="text" id="box1">
  <input type="text" id="box1">
  <input type="text" id="box1">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And JS

```
function sendBoxes(){
    var values = "'"+$('#box1').val()+"'"+$('#box2').val()+"'"+$('#box3').val()+"'";
    jQuery.ajax({
       url: "ajax_ajax.php",
       data: "boxes="+values,
       cache: false,
       error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Error.\n" + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
       }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
 <input id="box1" type="text" />
 <input id="box2" type="text" />
 <input id="box3" type="text" />
 <input id="submit_button" type="submit" />
```

JS

```
function submit(){
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "someurl.php",
  data:{'boxes':$('#box1').val()+","+$('#box2').val()+","+$('#box3').val()}
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
}
$("#submit_button").click(function(e) {
  submit();
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

This would check whether submit button is clicked and sends three box values separated by comma